# Variable Interpolation in Jquery code inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code, http://jsfiddle.net/hucw940s/
which has a for loop.

```
before
<div id="container">

</div>
after

for (i = 1; i < 4; i++){
  var showMe = $('<a href=# id="link' + i + '">')
    .append('click').click(function(){ alert('You clicked num: ' + i) });
  $('#container').append(
    $('<div id="div'+i+'">').append('this is div number: ' + i).append(showMe)
  ); 
}
```

so the links are generated with id=link1, link2, link3 etc, and the divs appended are the same, however the onclick code seems to put the var i in after the event, so on clicking any link they say "you clicked number 4"

How can I make this use the i from the clicked link inside the function that is called on click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are experiencing is the expected behavior based on your code.

However, what you are actually trying to do is pass in [event data](https://api.jquery.com/event.data/) to your [click](https://api.jquery.com/click/#click-eventData-handler) function.  This can be accomplished like this:

```js
for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    var showMe = $('<a href=# id="link' + i + '">').append('click')

    .click({value: i}, function (e) { alert('You clicked num: ' + e.data.value) });
  
    $('#container').append($('<div id="div' + i + '">').append('this is div number: ' + i).append(showMe));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

</div>
```

- First, you have to assign the event data, so we pass in an object
  `{value: i}` before we pass in the handler function.
- Then, in the handler function, we assign the variable `e` to the
  event, so we can access the data attribute.
- Finally, you access the value that was passed in by referencing
  `e.data.value`.

You can add as many event data objects as you want and reference them by name this way.

The reason your code is not working as you are expecting is because the variable `i` is already equal to `3` by the time the click event happens, since the `for` loop completes before you are able to click any of the links.

Hope this helps give you a better understanding of why your code is behaving the way it is and what you can do to fix it.

Comment: Thanks!  I could see that is was the fact that i was taking the post loop value, ie it is 4.  However I could not see why i was sometimes using the value inside the loop, and sometimes taking the value when the event was triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Store the id in a `data-attribute`.

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hucw940s/4/)